# Does "avail" make sense here?

Tags: meaning

My colleagues in India frequently use "avail" to mean "use" or "take advantage of" as in the following example:

> Avail our special offer for this event.

I have never seen "avail" used in the manner; and judging by Merriam-Webster, I shouldn't be seeing it now :-) But I am, so I'd like to know what I might be missing.

Note: British English is the dialect my colleagues are most familiar with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's normally used as _avail yourself of_ so _avail yourself of our special offer ..._ would be fine.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. That's how I've heard it, too. ...Would I be overstating matters to say that the usage in my example above is "wrong" or "grammatically incorrect"?

Comment: I don't know about _grammatical_ but your sentence _avail our special offer ..._ just isn't a form that I've ever heard _avail_ used in. I don't think you'd be overstating it if you said it was _very unusual_.

Comment: Your colleagues might avail themselves of an English dictionary, too. :-)

Comment: In all the dictionaries I've checked in, transitive _avail_ is defined as 'be of use / benefit / value ... to' not 'take advantage of' / 'make use of'. The idiomatic 'avail oneself of' is defined separately in the better treatments.

Comment: @LittleEva - It would be to no avail.

Answer (score 11):

This is an example of [**Indianism.**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indianism) vs avail *yourself of* our special offer.

> *Avail* our special offer for this event.
>
> This "**avail**" here is context dependent and could mean "get". (or
>   "use" or "take advantage of")

**The noun poses no problems**. It is used most frequently in the phrases
of no avail (his efforts were of no avail), to no avail (he tried the key
but to no avail), etc.

An Indianism is an English word or phrase **used in India** **that is not acceptable in *BrE or AmE***.

Some examples that you may ***frequent regularly*** :

- 'Kindly revert'- using the word revert to mean reply or respond.
- 'Discuss about'
- I am having a headache
- To Take Tension- to feel concerned or nervous .

Comment: Now we're umpteen nations divided by a common language. These are not acceptable in the English considered standard in the UK.

Comment: @Mysti Sinha, thanks for confirming "avail" as an Indianism.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, good point. I should have added that my question is in the context of standard U.S. English.

Comment: I've also seen "do the needful" used unironically.

Comment: In Indian usage, this seems to be very like the Mexican Spanish verb _aprovechar_, usually translated as "take advantage of". I well recall loudspeakers in front of stores exhorting _¡Aproveche ese oportunidad!_

Comment: @JohnLawler - I don't see the problem.  I just checked DLE and found "1. tr. Emplear útilmente algo, hacerlo provechoso o sacarle el máximo rendimiento. *Aprovechar la tela, el tiempo, la ocasión.*" https://dle.rae.es/aprovechar?m=form

Answer (score 2):

You are better off just ditching *avail* altogether and saying

> Help yourself to our special offer.

Comment: I agree, @Robusto. But is it "wrong"? As in, "grammatically wrong."

Comment: It is grammatically wrong not to use it with the reflexive pronoun, and it is stylistically wrong otherwise.

Comment: Why would it better to change _avail yourself of_ to _help yourself to_? Have we reached Idiocracy already? (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0387808/ )

Comment: @Frank Do you still say 'It is I'? No less an expert than Pullum says that this is ludicrous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That I do. Are you suggesting _avail yourself of_ is, or is becoming, obsolete?

Comment: @Frank: It calls attention to itself rather than to the communication, and will very likely sidetrack the entire conversation. If that is your intent, by all means go for it.

Comment: Is it that obscure a phrase now? That's a genuine question: I've not been to the UK for any length of time for decades.

Comment: I think it will always have a self-conscious ring to it.

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries flag this:  (avail oneself of) formal. Sensible people avoid certain registers (obscene, slang, informal, formal, archaic, technical ...) where their use would be likely to cause offence / confusion or be seen as ridiculous. Coupled with 'special offer', 'avail yourself of' is ludicrous.

Comment: @Robusto, thanks for the grammatical clarification.